# Save selected item in SelectList to DataBase

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save a selected item in a SelectList to my database, but for some reason my Id stays '0' all the time.

**This is the ViewModel I'm using:**

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        #region Properties

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Naam")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Waarschuwing")]
        public int WarningAmount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Inkoopwaarde")]
        public int Buy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Verkoopwaarde")]
        public int Sell { get; set; }

        public int FactoryId { get; set; }
        public SelectList FactoriesList { get; set; }

        #endregion 
    }
```

The view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Fabriek</label>
            <select asp-for="FactoryId" asp-items="Model.FactoriesList">
                <option>Kies een fabriek</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

And last, my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel();

            var factories = _context.Factories.ToList();
            model.FactoriesList = new SelectList(factories, "FactoryId", "Name");

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(
            [Bind("Name", "Type", "WarningAmount", "Buy", "Sell")] ProductViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ProductViewModel, Product>());
                var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                Product product = mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, Product>(model);

                product.Factory = _context.Factories.Where(w => w.FactoryId == model.FactoryId).First();

                _context.Products.Add(product);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
}
```

So, for some reason the model.FactoryId is staying `null` at ALL times. Tried a lot already and been struggeling for several hours.

Comment: You select and you `post` and in the `Post` action you always find `FactoryId` (that is, `model.FactoryId`) to be 0. Is that what you are saying? How about the other items in the ViewModel (Name, Type, etc)? Do they follow exactly what you input as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the `Bind` you have in the `Post` action to include the `FactoryId` from the `ProductViewModel`:

```
[Bind("Name", "Type", "WarningAmount", "Buy", "Sell", "FactoryId")]
```

Also, ensure that the data type for the `FactoryId` matches (`string` or `int`) with how the data actually input (for instance, using `string` for the dropdown list option instead of `int`)